# Git Pull with uncommitted changes

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

It often happens that I'll be working on something and notice another commit has been made on the main branch. More often than not I can't pull without either stashing (or committing) my changes. So I always stash my changes, pull, then re-apply my own changes to continue.

So basically I need to do the `stash -> pull -> apply` dance several times a day. Is there a feature I don't know about that will enable me to do this in one, and can it be done in Sourcetree?

Thanks.

Comment: Given that it sounds like you're avoiding the command line, you might not *want* to work the way I generally do, but: I personally try to avoid both `git stash` and `git pull` myself. Just run `git fetch` to obtain any new commit. This will update your remote-tracking names, which will give you access to the new commit(s). You can inspect them with other Git commands, such as `git log -p` or `git show` or `git diff` and use that information to decide whether they're worth interrupting other work to deal with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can solve your problem:

`git pull --rebase --autostash`

Comment: Thanks, that has worked perfectly! It also seems there has been a request for this in SourceTree for many years but is still yet to be implemented: https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-1732

Comment: I am so glad that your problem is solved. There is another way to do it. I saw it in the link that you shared. Setting `git config --global rebase.autostash true` will allow you to write only `git pull --rebase`. You can also config it locally by `git config --local rebase.autostash true`

Comment: Yes, thank you @Prihex. I also tried the `config --global ...` command myself and found not only does it change the default behaviour of the command line but it also makes SourceTree's pull button work exactly as I wanted. So a definite win there. Thank you: (:

Comment: Good idea!. I couldn't think that. So, have a nice work :)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the question might be:

> I'm on branch `myBranch` and I want to catch `master` up to the remote without leaving `myBranch`. Can I?

If so, the answer is: usually. You can say

```
git fetch origin master:master
```

to update the local `master` branch provided this is a fast-forward — which it generally will be, in typical use patterns.

Note that SourceTree lets you peek at any commit (as a diff from the preceding commit) or diff any two commits (by selecting them). Thus you can usually tell quite easily what is germane about a branch.